# Need to export the python output of the below code to json (key : value) format file

Tags: python, json, excel

I am printing the column name, data type and the max length of the columns from an Excel file.

Below is the code and the output, need to export the output to the json file.

#### Excel file (assignment.xlsx):

```xml
<html>
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Amount received</th>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Flag</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Educationsl</td>
      <td>1422.00</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>2018-11-30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

#### Output

```
Column Name : Type
Data type : String
Size  : 11

Column Name : Amountreceived
Data type : Float
Size  : 6

Column Name : Currency
Data type : String
Size  : 3

Column Name : Flag
Data type : String
Size  : 1

Column Name : Date
Data type : Float
Date format  : ddmmyyyy
```

#### Code

```
import string
import re
import datetime
import xlrd
loc = r"C:\Users\Documents\PythonStuff\assignment.xlsx"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(sheet.ncols):
    print ("Column Name : " + re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', sheet.cell_value(0, i).replace(' ','_')))
##Data Type
    if str(sheet.cell_type(1,i)) == '1':
        print  ("Data type : String ")
    elif isinstance(sheet.cell_value(1,i), float) == True:
        print  ("Data type : Float ")
    elif str(sheet.cell_type(1,i)) =='3':
        print  ("Data type : Date ")
## Date Format
    if str(sheet.cell_type(1,i)) =='3':
        print ("Date format  : " + "ddmmyyyy" +"\n ")
    else:
        print ("Size  : " + str(len (str(sheet.cell_value(1,i))))+"\n ")
```

#### Desired output

```
{"Excel": [{"Type": "Educational", "Amount received": "1422.00", "Currency": "USD", "Flag": "N", "Date": "2018-11-30"} ]}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module?

Comment: @mkrieger1: {"Excel": [{"Type": "Educational", "Amount received": "1422.00", "Currency": "USD", "Flag": "N", "Date": "2018-11-30"} ]}

Comment: @user5173426 : Tried json module, but not sure how to integrate it with the existing code

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to use the values of the 1st row as the dict keys and every row is an item in a the list. Add this to you code:

```
keys = [i.value for i in sheet.row(0)]
sheet_dict = {'Excel': list()}

for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    row_dict = {}
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        row_dict[keys[col]] = sheet.cell_value(rowx=row, colx=col)
    sheet_dict['Excel'].append(row_dict)

print(sheet_dict)
```

Or if you want a pretty output:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(sheet_dict, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Comment: Hello Frans, thanks for the answer provided. But the above code will print the data from the excel sheet. Instead I need to print the structure of the table (excel file) i.e its column name the data type of the value that column holds and the maximum length.